# Wicket 1.5 Non modal window

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I need to create a **non-modal** popup dialog, which can be dragged and resized by the user. 
[This](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/modal-window?0) example is great, but is a modal dialog. I don't want to block the user from scrolling the main web page.
Is there any component built in to Wicket that I can use, or do I need to use a Javascript library such as YUI or Dojo?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but it is in fact possible to scroll the page down when showing the dialog in the example page. You can also set `position:fixed` to the style of the main dialog (the one with `class="wicket-modal"`) to make the dialog stay on screen while scrolling. If you want to let the user interact with the background, you can just define `z-index:-1` for the `wicket-mask-dark` class. Having never used this component myself, maybe you could extend the component and tweak these stylings yourself with `AttributeModifier`s.

Comment: I'll do some experimenting over Christmas with this. In the past I've just used a simple Javascript alert dialog, and that did block everything until it was dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use [jQwicket](http://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/) for this, which is a JQuery/Wicket integration library

It has a load of useful components, but the one I can use for this particular case is the `DialogWebMarkupContainer` component.

JQwicket gives me a fairly painless way of using Javascript, using the Java I know and love. That's as it should be :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your concern with "blocking the user from scrolling the main web page" correctly, but maybe you should look into [WiQuery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/) - escpecially [this example](http://wiquery-examples.appspot.com/?wicket%3abookmarkablePage=%3aorg.odlabs.wiquery.examples.dialog.DialogPage). These dialogs still let you interact with the underlying page.

Comment: Thanks. That's an option, I'll look into it.